# Multi Line If Statement

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have this if

```
if (hours.Text.Length < 2 || minute.Text.Length < 2)
{
    DialogResult dlgresult = MessageBox.Show("Insert Hour or Minute", 
                                             "First Application",
                                             MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                                             MessageBoxIcon.Error);

}
```

This will insert the hours without minutes or the minutes without hours *but the MessageBox appears*.

How can I show this MessageBox when only the hour's and minute's length is 2 or longer?

Comment: What do you mean by, "2 or plus"?  Greater than 2? Also, "i have insert the hours without", what does that mean?  What are you inserting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the && operator instead of ||

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the box if `hours.Text.Length` **and** `minute.Text.Length` has the value of 2 or greater like you said, then your code should be:

```
if (hours.Text.Length >= 2 && minute.Text.Length >= 2)
            {
                DialogResult dlgresult = MessageBox.Show("Insert Hour or Minute", "First Application",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            }
```

respectivley you can use the following code to show the box if either of the variables is >= 2:

```
   if (hours.Text.Length >= 2 || minute.Text.Length >= 2)
                {
                    DialogResult dlgresult = MessageBox.Show("Insert Hour or Minute", "First Application",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            }
```